# можете объяснить коротко что делает map

Tags: c++

можете объяснить коротко что делает map

Comment: Хранит объекты типа "ключ":"значение"

Comment: map  может лежать на столе,  висеть на стене... Если речь идет об ассоциативном массиве  std::map, то читайте учебник и найдете ответ

Comment: это как std::set (в том смысле что тоже сбалансированное бинарное дерево поиска), но дерево поиска по ключу, и для каждого ключа у вас ещё есть некое значение, которое вы можете модифицировать или просто читать. поиск вставка удаление - `O(log(N))`. Ещё есть `unordered_map` - это уже хеш таблица, в ней вставка поиск и удаление в среднем выполняется за константное время, но в худшем случае (тут я могу ошибаться) за линейное

Answer (score 1):

Если по простому, то std::map -- это контейнер, хранящий пары ключ:значение. Небольшой пример.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map <std::string, int> people;
    people["Alice"] = 22;
    people["Bob"] = 34;
    people["Charlie"] = 28;

    for(std::map<std::string,int>::iterator it = people.begin(); it != people.end(); ++it)
    {
       std::cout << "Name: " << (*it).first << " Age: " << (*it).second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В примере мы создаём контейнер people хранящий пары "Имя:Возраст", добавили в контейнер данные трёх человек и затем вывели эти данные в консоль.

Comment: После таких `for (std::map<std::string, int>::iterator ...` у меня бы пропало желание изучать язык. 2018 год на дворе, есть `auto`.